# Flutter, quadraticBezierTo which is x and y?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

in above scenario, what point is the x1 and y1 and x2 and y2???

for

```
Path path = Path();
path.quadraticBezierTo(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/quadraticBezierTo.html says:

> Adds a quadratic bezier segment that curves from the current point to the given point (x2,y2), using the control point (x1,y1).

That is, (x1, y1) is the "handle point" in your picture, and (x2, y2) is the end point.

Comment: how to give starting point then ????????

Comment: @SULPHURICACID The starting point is the current position. You can set it with `Path.moveTo()`.